# Understanding AudioTrack Assertion in Android

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

In my Android app, I'm using the AudioTrack API to output audio bytes that I receive from a RFCOMM Bluetooth connection. The audio plays as expected and is very clear. However, the app occasionally crashes due to the following assertion in AudioTrackShared.cpp:

```
stepCount <= mUnreleased && mUnreleased <= mFrameCount
```

I'm not really sure of what this assertion entails, but does anyone have an idea of what could cause this issue? I can provide additional source code if needed:

My setup for AudioTrack:

```
int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
mAudioPlayer = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, minSize * 4, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Comment: Are you reusing the buffer you write to AudioTrack?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli I create a new array of size 64 every time I write to AudioTrack.

Comment: Is it the value you get from AudioTrach.getMinBufferSize ?

Comment: It isn't, but I don't see why that would be causing issues?

Comment: I believe you're feeding the AudioTrack with very few bytes, but it's an hypothesis. Have you tried with just minSize instead of minSize * 4 when you create the AudioTrack?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli I think that making the array of size minBufferSize actually resolved the issue. You should write a formal answer in order to get the bounty :)

Comment: You can also get this error is you create multiple `AudioTrack` objects and call `.read` on both of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make AudioTrack buffer size the same you get from minBufferSize. That could fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

#### Hidden Bug

The error is **not** directly related to the `audioBuffer` size vs. `minBufferSize`. Assuming that these two must be identical is an API misunderstanding, if not misuse. **(†)**

The reason behind this apparent fix is that having identical sizes ensures that the `audioBuffer` is copied in full during `mAudioPlayer.write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length)`, each time, every time.

The actual reason for the crash is that `audioBuffer`, when larger than `minBufferSize`, may not have been copied in full, then discarded before `mAudioPlayer.write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length)` had a chance to complete.

#### Solutions

- Check `audioBuffer` allocations and deallocations
- In a multi-threaded or async environment, ensure that `audioBuffer` has been consumed in between allocations.

**(†)**

1. `AudioTrack` buffer size > `audioBuffer` size:
   you may have many small packets arriving irregularly and can take advantage of the `AudioTrack` buffering system to compensate for these irregularities
2. `AudioTrack` buffer size == `audioBuffer` size:
   1 to 1 match ; `mAudioPlayer.write` is pretty much guaranteed to have copied `audioBuffer` exactly into `AudioTrack` buffer when returning
3. `AudioTrack` buffer size < `audioBuffer` size:
   the track will iterate through the `audioBuffer` as needed ; `audioBuffer` life cycle better lasts long enough

*In all cases, `audioBuffer` must remain allocated until consumed, and a **new** buffer presented to `mAudioPlayer.write` before it runs out of data to avoid gaps in playback.*