# Android AudioRecorder Assertion failed: !(stepCount <= mUnreleased && mUnreleased <= mFrameCount)

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am using audio recorder, i am not able to identify where the error is thrown! the app crashes ...

```
 for (int rate : new int[]{8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100}) {
        mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat
                .CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    }


 mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                mBufferSize);
```

i refered stack but didn;t find relevant answer...
stack strace :

```
01-05 18:25:19.863 21646-23485/com.voicy.demo A/AudioTrackShared: Assertion failed: !(stepCount <= mUnreleased && mUnreleased <= mFrameCount)
01-05 18:25:19.863 21646-23485/com.voicy.demo A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000548e (code=-6), thread 23485 (AudioRecorder T)
01-05 18:25:20.333 1061-1107/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '424b68b0 com.voicy.demo/com.voicy.demo.ui.HomePageActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-05 18:25:20.333 1061-1107/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '42d324d0 com.voicy.demo/com.voicy.demo.ui.HomePageActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-05 18:25:20.333 1061-1107/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '424b3a60 com.voicy.demo/com.voicy.demo.ui.ChatMessageActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: I'm Also having the same problem

Comment: i am still not getting the solution

Answer (score 0):

1. What's with:

   ```
   for (int rate : new int[]{8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100}) {
       mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat
       .CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
   }
   ```

   This is calculating `mBufferSize` with different values, eventually ending with `44100`, which admittedly will be a safe number.

   In this case, it should be:

   ```
   mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                                              RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                                              RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
   ```
2. Error is likely caused by the source buffer being disposed in mid-air.

Get inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799061/218152) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939252/218152) StackOverflow answer.